# Twig, Render duplicado si uso includes en la plantilla

Tags: php, twig

Estoy probando Twig (actualmente soy noob en twig es mi primera vez).
Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

**main.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

{% include 'header.tpl' %}

    <body>

    {% include 'logo.tpl' %}

        content

    {% include 'footer.tpl' %}

    </body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once PLUGIN_PATH.'Twig/Autoloader.php';
    Twig_Autoloader::register();

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(VIEWS_PATH);

    $options = [
        'autoescape' => false,
        'strict_variables' => false
    ];

    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, $options);
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('main.tpl);
    echo $template->render(['title' => 'myTemplate']);
?>
```

**header.tpl**

```
<head>
    <!-- head content -->
</head>
```

**logo.tpl**

```
<img src="logo.png">
```

Hasta este punto todo bien (aparentemente), pero en la carpeta de mi desarollo no existe un logo.png, así que sé que me arrojará un error en la consola, pero para mi sorpresa el error me lo arroja dos veces.

Si intento reproducir otro error (como por ejemplo poner otra imagen sin source) me muestra el error dos veces también.Es raro porque el html del layout no lo duplica pero por alguna extraña razón el error si.

¿Esto es normal? ¿o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Editado, no se como acabe en el stackoverflow en español si estaba en haciendo el post en el de ingles

Comment: Ningún problema. Puede pasarle a cualquiera... Bienvenido! Quizás estás cargando otra imagen en  `footer.tpl`.. Revisaste el código de ese? ... Por cierto, estás incluyendo la imagen antes de abrir el `<body>`

Comment: En el footer no tengo absolutamente nada solo un <footer></footer> y me pareció irrelevante colocarlo, lo de la variable $tiwg y el include de la imagen fue un error de edición. básicamente si coloco otra imagen sin source o simulo un error de javascript me arroja el error en la consola dos veces, no se mucho de twig solo seguí parte de la documentación.

Comment: Acabo de editar el post para que se vea mejor pero básicamente con ese layout sigo teniendo el error doble, loque me es raro es que no me duplique el html

Comment: No lo pude reproducir. Usé [este template](http://twigfiddle.com/jwdq4a) y el error aparece 1 sola vez... ¿Probaste en una ventana de incógnito? Quizás es algún script que tengas cargado en Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que dices en `twig`, no se hace de esa forma. Te indico unos ejemplos:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block css %}   
    {% endblock %}
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**contenido.html.twig**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header" style="font-size: 30px;">TEST</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br/>
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
{% endblock %}
```

El archivo que muestra el contenido, tiene que tener al principio de todo `{% extends "nombre_archivo.html.twig" %}` para indicar que depende de ese archivo.

Luego esto: `{% block content %}` indica en que parte del archivo base ira colocado

Espero que te sirva